# Replace NAs with mean of the same column of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to replace NAs present in a column of a DATA TABLE with the mean of the same column. I am doing the following. But it is not working.

```
ww <- data.table(iris)

ww <- ww[1:5 , ]

ww[1,1] <- NA

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1:           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa


ww[is.na(Sepal.Length) , Sepal.Length:= mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = T)]

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1:          NaN         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Why am I getting NaN in place of NA when it should have been the mean of the rest of the values (4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0)?

What is the alternate of acheiving this in case something is wrong with this syntax?

I want to the syntax for the data table.

Comment: The problem is that you're subsetting the dataset first, then applying an operation to the `Sepal.Length` column, which contains only a single `NA` at this point.

Comment: @AkhilNair did not get you. Could you please give an example?

Comment: @RHertel your solution is replacing the whole column not just NA.

Comment: Why are you replacing missing values with the mean? There might be better solutions for the issue you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`na.aggregate` in the zoo package replaces NAs with the mean of the non-NAs in the same column:

```
library(zoo)

ww[, Sepal.Length := na.aggregate(Sepal.Length)]
```

Comment: `na.aggregate` is a function in zoo.   Note the `library` statement.

Comment: Thanks so much. Before I make a new post, is there a way to index the solution so it takes the average of the non-NA columns by some other grouping, such as species?

Comment: `ww[ , ..., by = Species]`

Answer (score 13):

While the `zoo` answer is pretty nice it requires new dependency.
Using just `data.table` you could do the following.

```
library(data.table)

# prepare data
ww = data.table(iris[1:5,])
ww[1, Sepal.Length := NA]

# solution
ww[, Sepal.Length.mean := mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE) # calculate mean
   ][is.na(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Length := Sepal.Length.mean # replace NA with mean
     ][, Sepal.Length.mean := NULL # remove mean col
       ][] # just prints
```

While it may looks biggish comparing to zoo's, it is performance efficient as all steps are made using *update by reference* `:=`.
It can also be easily tuned to replace NA with mean by group, just using `by` argument in data.table.

Answer (score 7):

Your attempt subsetted the table first, selecting

```
> ww[is.na(Sepal.Length)]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1:   

    NA         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

so any further operations can only 'see' these rows - i.e. `Sepal.Length` can only see that one `NA`.

The `data.table` solution you want is below - it looks at the whole table and replaces the `NA`s with the means using an `ifelse`.

```
ww[, Sepal.Length := ifelse(is.na(Sepal.Length), mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE), Sepal.Length)]
```

Comment: Or `ww[, Sepal.Length := replace(Sepal.Length, is.na(Sepal.Length), mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm=TRUE))]` since `ifelse` is typically slow. Annoying that `Sepal.Length` needs to be typed out four times here.

Answer (score 6):

In base R:

```
ww$Sepal.Length[is.na(ww$Sepal.Length)] <- mean(ww$Sepal.Length, na.rm = T)
```

Comment: can you transform this syntax to that of data.table?

Answer (score 4):

It is not taking the mean of the entire Sepal.Length column; only the 1 column that you have chosen.

Rather use:

```
ww[is.na(Sepal.Length) , Sepal.Length:= mean(ww$Sepal.Length, na.rm=TRUE)]
```

Comment: is this syntax valid for data.table?

Comment: @user3664020 it is now.

Comment: This is probably bad practice to call `Sepal.Length` within the scope of `ww` from the global scope. With another example, you might have reordered the columns which would screw subsequent things up if you called `ww` globally.

Comment: @AkhilNair, can't see why columns being reordered would screw up obtaining mean.. Do you've an example in mind that you could share?

Comment: I didn't mean to say it would go wrong with the mean - just that it was a bad habit to get in to, i.e. if I were to copy a column using the global scope, it would be fine unless I had reordered the table in the same line.

Comment: @AkhilNair, you'll have to ping me (else I don't get notified). I can't see why it's a bad habit still. The purpose is exactly right. I've no idea what your last sentence means (copy a column using the global scope??). Example please.

Comment: @Arun I mean the difference between `df = data.table(a = c(1, 2), b = c(4, 3))`, then `df[order(b), c := a]` and `df[order(b), c := df$a]`, where the latter is a mistake I made and a habit I wanted to get out of (i.e. not using the locally scoped variables), when moving from base R to `data.table`. I can understand that this might be more of a personal preference thing though.

Comment: @AkhilNair, thanks. This case is different, where we need exactly the indices extracted from `i` to be all replaced with the mean of entire column. The intent is quite clear here.

Answer (score 3):

`tidyr` has a built in function, `replace_na` you can use for this:

```
library(tidyr)
ww %>% replace_na(list(Sepal.Length = mean(.$Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

just one line will do the trick with `fcoalesce`:

```
ww[, Sepal.Length := fcoalesce(Sepal.Length, mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE))]
ww

#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <num>       <num>        <num>       <num>  <fctr>
#> 1:          4.8         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```