# Conditional cumulative mean for each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
id   a   b
1    AA  2
1    AB  5
1    AA  1
2    AB  2
2    AB  4
3    AB  4
3    AB  3
3    AA  1
```

I need to calculate the cumulative mean for each record within each group and excluding the case where `a == 'AA'`, So sample output should be:

```
id   a   b  mean
1    AA  2   -
1    AB  5   5
1    AA  1   5
2    AB  2   2
2    AB  4   (4+2)/2
3    AB  4   4
3    AB  3   (4+3)/2
3    AA  1   (4+3)/2
3    AA  4   (4+3)/2
```

I tried to achieve it using dplyr and cummean by getting an error.

```
df <- df %>%
       group_by(id) %>%
       mutate(mean = cummean(b[a != 'AA']))
```

> Error: incompatible size (123), expecting 147 (the group size) or 1

Can you suggest a better way to achieve the same in R ?

Comment: Looks like you want the pairwise mean of consecutive values in the same group and not the cummean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to reconstruct the `cummean` by dividing the adjusted `cumsum` by the adjusted count.  As a one-liner:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(cumsum(b * (a != 'AA')) / cumsum(a != 'AA'))
```

We can make this a little nicer (the "multiply by `a!='AA'` - magic!" is the ugliness in my mind) by taking out the `a != 'AA'` as a column

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(relevance = 0+(a!='AA'), 
           mean = cumsum(relevance * b) / cumsum(relevance))
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be an easier approach.  Here, we group by 'id'.  Create a new column 'Mean' by first converting the elements in 'b' that corresponds to 'AA' in 'a' to `NA` (`b*NA^(a=='AA')`).  `NA^(a=='AA')` gives an output of `NA` for 'AA' in 'a' and 1 for all other values.  So, when we multiply by 'b', it replaces the 1 with the values in 'b' while NA remains as such.  We use `na.aggregate` to replace the 'NA' with the `mean` of non-NA elements in each group, then wrap with `cummean` to get the cumulative mean.  If the first value in each group for 'a' is 'AA', we can get `NA` for that by multiplying with `NA^(row_number()==1 & a=='AA')`.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(Mean= cummean(na.aggregate(b*NA^(a=='AA')))*
                 NA^(row_number()==1 & a=='AA'))
# Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
#Groups: id [3]

#      id     a     b  Mean
#   (int) (chr) (int) (dbl)
#1     1    AA     2    NA
#2     1    AB     5   5.0
#3     1    AA     1   5.0
#4     2    AB     2   2.0
#5     2    AB     4   3.0
#6     3    AB     4   4.0
#7     3    AB     3   3.5
#8     3    AA     1   3.5
#9     3    AA     4   3.5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
a = c("AA", 
"AB", "AA", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AA", "AA"), b = c(2L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L)), .Names = c("id", "a", "b"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thumbs up for `na.aggregate`. There is no function in R, unknown to @akrun.

Comment: @Khashaa Thanks for the vote.  I got reminded of the `na.aggregate` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564034/replace-nas-with-mean-of-the-same-column-of-a-data-table/32564334#32564334)

Comment: @akrun there might be the case where first 2 or 3 rows have NA in a. In those cases, mean should be NA.

Comment: @DheerajSingh You should have provided an input data that mimics the original dataset.