# dplyr bug with data.table backend [in dplyr 0.4.3 or earlier]

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

As I was browsing through the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567685/conditional-cumulative-mean-for-each-group-in-r), I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568710/4380497) works exactly as expected with `data.frame`.

```
library(dplyr) # dplyr_0.4.3  
library(data.table) # data.table_1.9.5 
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                     a = c("AA", 
                           "AB", "AA", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AA", "AA"), b = c(2L, 5L, 
                                                                                  1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L)), .Names = c("id", "a", "b"),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))


df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(relevance=+(a!='AA')) %>%
  mutate(mean=cumsum(relevance * b) / cumsum(relevance))

 Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
Groups: id [3]

     id     a     b relevance  mean
  (int) (chr) (int)     (int) (dbl)
1     1    AA     2         0   NaN
2     1    AB     5         1   5.0
3     1    AA     1         0   5.0
4     2    AB     2         1   2.0
5     2    AB     4         1   3.0
6     3    AB     4         1   4.0
7     3    AB     3         1   3.5
8     3    AA     1         0   3.5
9     3    AA     4         0   3.5
```

However when run with `data.table`, it resulted in something beyond my comprehension.

```
setDT(df) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(relevance=+(a!='AA')) %>%
  mutate(mean=cumsum(relevance * b) / cumsum(relevance))

Source: local data table [9 x 5]

     id     a     b relevance     mean
  (int) (chr) (int)     (int)    (dbl)
1     1    AA     2         0      NaN
2     1    AB     5         1 5.000000
3     1    AA     1         0 5.000000
4     2    AB     2         1 3.500000
5     2    AB     4         1 3.666667
6     3    AB     4         1 3.750000
7     3    AB     3         1 3.600000
8     3    AA     1         0 3.600000
9     3    AA     4         0 3.600000
```

Is this an expected behaviour? If so, is there any guideline on when not to use `data.table` backend with `dplyr`?

Comment: I think you don't need two `mutate` here `setDT(df) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(relevance=+(a!='AA'), Mean= cumsum(relevance*b)/cumsum(relevance))` works as expected.  I think what is happening is after the first `mutate`, the grouping is gone for some strange reason, and now, it is using ungrouped `cumsum`

Comment: Looking at row 5, shouldn' t `cumsum(relevance * b) / cumsum(relevance)) = ([4*1] + [2*1] + [5*1])/(3) = 11/3 = 3.666667`, i.e. the `data.table` answer?

Comment: @akrun Thanks for comment. I want to know how a seemingly innocuous extra `mutate` generates such behavior.

Comment: It may be a bug that mess up the grouping.  In general, a second mutate is not needed.

Comment: Oh right I see. It seems to have forgotten about the grouping.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/919

Comment: @Frank You could post that as an answer..

Comment: @Frank, Thank you very much. You should post that as an answer as akrun suggested.

Comment: @ExperimenteR Okay thanks, done. Maybe the shortest answer I've ever written.

Comment: @Frank, thanks again for important lesson: when something goes wrong, check the github issues first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug that causes grouping to be dropped after `mutate` on a data.table [was resolved in 0.5.0](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/919).

Comment: It might be worth saying that the bug has been closed.

Comment: @Zag Thanks. Edited the question and answer.