# replace NAs in a column of a data.table with means of the same column grouped by a factor

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following sample data table

```
steps.dt = data.table(steps=rep(0:2, each=3), 
date=as.factor(rep(c("10/2/2012", "10/3/2012", "10/4/2012"), each = 3)), interval = as.factor(rep(c(0,5,10), each = 3)))
```

inserting a few NAs

```
steps.dt[c(2,5,8),"steps"]=NA
```

the table now looks like this

```
   steps      date interval
1:     0 10/2/2012        0
2:    NA 10/2/2012        0
3:     0 10/2/2012        0
4:     1 10/3/2012        5
5:    NA 10/3/2012        5
6:     1 10/3/2012        5
7:     2 10/4/2012       10
8:    NA 10/4/2012       10
9:     2 10/4/2012       10
```

Now, I am trying to replace the NAs in the column "steps" with the means of steps grouped by the factor "interval"

I have looked at some of the posts on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564034/replace-nas-with-mean-of-the-same-column-of-a-data-table) but that I need the replacement to be grouped by a factor is complicating it. Is there a way to do this without using a loop? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `na.aggregate` from `zoo` to replace the 'NA' with the `mean` of the 'steps' after grouping by 'interval'

```
library(zoo)
steps.dt[, steps := na.aggregate(steps), interval]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
steps.dt = steps.dt %>% group_by(interval) %>% 
                        mutate(steps = ifelse(is.na(steps),mean(steps,na.rm = T),steps))
```

Comment: Fyi, you can do something like `replace(steps, is.na(steps), mean(steps, na.rm=TRUE))` instead.

Comment: @Frank but he needs it grouped on 'interval'. A simple replace replaces NA's with overall mean of steps

Comment: Sure, I meant you could use this instead of the `ifelse` part (keeping the group_by). The `ifelse` function generally has some quirks and speed problems and doesn't seem the most natural option when the goal is to replace some values.