# Replace NA and NaN with column mean across multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, nan, na

I have a data frame similar to the following, containing both NA and NaN values.

```
myinput <- data.frame("Date" = c("20010331", "20010331", "20010331", "20010630", "20010630"), "A" = c(3, NA, 5, NaN, 2), "B" = c(4, NA, 7, NaN, 8), "C" = c(6, NA, 5, NaN, 7), "D" = c(1, NA, 3, NaN, 8))
```

I would like to replace Na and NaN values with the column mean, and loop this over all columns. Also, I would like to separate this on date. For example, NA in column A would be the average of all column A values with date 20010331, and NaN in column A would be the average of all column A values with date 20010630.

Is there any way to do this? Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How do you want to calculate the mean? Should the length include `NA` and `nan`s or exclude them?

Comment: Exclude. Sorry should've clarified on that point @NelsonGon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
myinput %>% 
   group_by(Date) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()),~ifelse(is.na(.) | is.nan(.),
                                         mean(.,na.rm=TRUE),.))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   Date [2]
  Date         A     B     C     D
  <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 20010331     3   4     6       1
2 20010331     4   5.5   5.5     2
3 20010331     5   7     5       3
4 20010630     2   8     7       8
5 20010630     2   8     7       8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can achieve the same result with **data.table**, you can have a look at how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564034/replace-nas-with-mean-of-the-same-column-of-a-data-table).